# Why I can't see some controls when I'm using Syncfusion to docking them in C#.NET?

Tags: c#, controls, dock, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion 6.1 to dock my controls in my main Form in C#.NET. When I use below code to show my control, I can't find some controls in my form.

```
MainPageDockingManager.SetDockVisibility(myControl, true);
```

I know that Syncfusion store the state of the docked windows and I think my controls are out of my screen range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncfusion stores its docking information in "SyncfusionToolsStateInfo.bin" file. if you want to reset your docking information, you can delete this file. You determined the address of "SyncfusionToolsStateInfo.bin" file in syncfusion setup.

Also you can use below code to dock your window to your main form:

```
mainPageDockingManager.SetDockVisibility(controlName, true);
mainPageDockingManager.DockControl(controlName, this, DockingStyle.Right, 150);
```

"this" object is the reference of your main form. After executing the code, you can save the state of your windows.